# Exit from tailing a file - In perl

Tags: perl, tail-recursion, filehandle, file-handling

I have this bit of code which basically tails a file.
This file is populated with nearly 100 entries every second.

```
open (MYFILE, 'output.txt');
for (;;)
{
    while (<MYFILE>)
    {
        chomp;
        my $test=$_;
        if  ($test =~ m/^ok/)
        {
            $passed++;
            print "Number of passed :$passed\n";
            print "Number of failed :$failed\n";
        }
        elsif ($test =~ m/^not/)
        {
            $failed++;
            print "Number of passed :$passed\n";
            print "Number of failed :$failed\n";
        }
        elsif ($test =~ m/^The time taken is: (.*)/)
        { push (@array, "$1") ; }
        $row++;

    }
sleep (5);
print "It has been ".(time - $time)."seconds\n";
seek(MYFILE, 0, 1);

}
```

All of this works fine, but **I want this perl script to exit automatically when the file `output.txt` is not getting populated any further.**

Is there a way apart from using a flag technique? A provision made by perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built into Perl that I know of. You could check the file size (using `tell`), record the time when the file size changes, and exit if too much time has passed since the last change.

Comment: I am unaware of the `tell` function, can someone show me a sample?

Comment: `$current_position_in_bytes = tell FILEHANDLE`

Comment: @perlnewbie - Just to add to what mob said -- if you use `tell` just after seeking to the end of the file, that tells you the file size (at least at the time the seek was done).

Comment: Thanks guys I got it figured out.